# How to count occurrences in an array PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, count, echo

i have created a simple web app with PHP, MySQL and CodeIgniter.The app is for ordering clothes and the user can make new orders or view his old ones. When he views his order i print on the screen the amount of clothes that he/she has ordered. Now what i want is to print the clothes that are ordered based on the color, for example if the user has ordered 3 black t-shirts, 2 green and 1 red, i want to print them on the screen. I have managed for every product of the order to pass the color information in a table.

If the user makes add the product he wants to buy in this order (black, green, green, black,red, black) then the array would look like this :

`$color= array("black","green","green","black","red","black")`

Now what i want is to count how many times every color is in the array, and pass that information in a new array in order to print it.
Thanks in advance, and sorry if my question violates the community rules.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [array_count_values()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php). It counts all the values of an array
and returns an `array` using the values of array as `keys` and their frequency in array as values.

```php
$result = array_count_values($color);
```

It gives you the following result:

```php
Array
(
    [black] => 3
    [green] => 2
    [red] => 1
)
```

[Live demo](https://implode.io/S0KO0C)

Answer (score 1):

please use the below code for count the occurrences.

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```